# how to accept data into textbox that accepts only culture codes like en-US in vb 6

Tags: vb6

Plz tell me some suggestions how to restrict input data to accept only culture codes like en-US in Textbox.

I have tried this code but its accepting all 5 letter characters...i want it to accept only culture codes which are in the format of en-US

```
if Length(textbox1.text) > 5 then
  enter only five chars
else if Length(textbox1.text) < 5 then
  enter up to five chars
```

Comment: Does "Button1.click" belong to the code snippet?

Comment: no it is not the part of code ...

Comment: For this kind of data, we should have combobox listing all the codes so that user will not be able to key-in but pick from the authentic codes provided in the combobox

Answer (score 0):

Using the KeyPress event you can check the ASCII value ot the symbol imputted. Should it be not of a correct value then set it to 0.

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii > 190 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

You may include more checks - for numeric symbols and so on.

You may find this useful: http://www.asciitable.com/